# Python, Django: get data from select-fields inside a table

Tags: python, django, html-table, drop-down-menu, request

inside my app I have a table that contains a select-field in each row. After pressing the submit-button I would like to receive all the selected values inside a list (or something else that's usable):

**template:**

```
<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <table name="table-example">
        <thead>
            ...
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for item in list_example %}
                <tr>
                    <td>...</td>
                    <td>...</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="select-example">
                            {% for item in list_selections %}
                                <option name="option-example" value="{{ item }}">{{ item }}</option>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

When trying to receive data from  I only get one field!

```
if request.method == "POST":
    data = request.POST.get('option-example', None)
```

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing here? Or is this even possible?
Thanks for all your help and have a great day!

Comment: Do you have the same `name` value for each option? That won't work as the value of an input can be only from one unique name attribute

Comment: Probably is because you have multiple `select` with the same `name`. That's why it is only sending 1.

Comment: Thanks! Added {{ forloop.counter }} into the name field, so I can address each field separatley.